# Unable to update cloud backend api in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using cloud backend api in app engine to generate my backend for my android app. I'm using android studio as IDE. I am able to create the backend api and add it to my android app but when I try to change something in the api methods and re-run the application, my android app is not getting the latest method changes.

I tried to do a gradle sync even then it's not updating. And when I try to increment the api version of backend api its working but I dont want to change the api I just want to update the api.

I found the gradle's maven local repo inside .m2 folder and found my api backend generated within it and deleted it and tried again to install client libraries from android studio.
And when I built it, it got the latest changes within the api.

But when I try to run the project, it is saying " UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] com.android.dx.util.DexException: Multiple dex files define" error.

Comment: Im having the same issue and it is driving me insane. I think it is related to the backend module pulling in the same dependencies as the android app itself but i cn not work out which ones i need to exclude.